# ajax security preventing the url access over browser

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, security

i have default.asp and it contacts with 3 different *.asp via ajax. My question is if a person try to execute these *.asp pages without accessing default.asp if people try to open those pages as an url. http://sample.com/ajax1.asp?get=foo is an example how can prevent that kind of accesses to my ajax pages.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why (all other things being equal) accessing these asp pages would be a breach of security where accessing the default.asp is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the call is an AJAX request looking for the `HTTP_X-Requested-With` header, but even if you can detect an AJAX call, **you should authenticate all requests**, because a malicious user could spoof all the headers easily.

Detecting the AJAX header:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X-Requested-With") = "XMLHttpRequest" Then
   ''do stuff
Else
```

Comment: I tried that but Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X-Requested-With") did not work. There is no result comes from that always null. I saw in many cases php and asp.net uses that. However your recommandation about authentication is gonna be useful for me thanks. ps: If you find a way to detect I'll be glad.

Comment: The header is added by most Javascript frameworks, like jQuery. How are you doing the AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding the bold line to ajax requests.

```
    function callit()
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){document.getElementById('alp').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}
     xmlhttp.open("get", "call.asp", true);
     **xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");**
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
```